# How to run dymanic SQL through IKJEFT01 Utility?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

How can we pass parameters in SQL query while executing IKJEFT01? Example:

```
//UNLOAD    EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN   DD *  DSN SYSTEM(DB2X) RETRY(120)
RUN PROGRAM(DSNTIAUL)
PLAN(DSNTIAUL) -
PARM('SQL')
END
//SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSUDUMP  DD SYSOUT=D
//SYSREC00  DD DSN=FCSTN.AK.XXXXXX,
//          DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//SYSPUNCH  DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSIN     DD *
SELECT * FROM ABC.DEF WHERE XYZ='999'   
/*
```

Instead of giving value in sql query as '999' i want to pass the value through a variable.
How this can be done? Plz help...!

Comment: A JCL variable or  TWS/OPCA variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a separate step, prior to your UNLOAD step, that writes the variable line(s) of SQL to a temporary file.  Then concatenate that temporary file with the unchanging lines of SQL.

Freehand...

```
//SETVAR   EXEC PGM=PRM2FILE,PARM='WHERE XYZ=''&VAL'''
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
//OUTPUT01 DD  DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE),
//             LRECL=80,
//             AVGREC=U,
//             RECFM=FB,
//             SPACE=(80,(1,1),RLSE)
//*
//UNLOAD    EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN   DD *  DSN SYSTEM(DB2X) RETRY(120)
RUN PROGRAM(DSNTIAUL)
PLAN(DSNTIAUL) -
PARM('SQL')
END
//SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSUDUMP  DD SYSOUT=D
//SYSREC00  DD DSN=FCSTN.AK.XXXXXX,
//          DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//SYSPUNCH  DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSIN     DD *
SELECT * FROM ABC.DEF
//          DD  DISP=(OLD,PASS),DSN=*.SETVAR.OUTPUT01
//*
```

...where PRM2FILE is a program you write to take whatever is in the parm field and write it to the OUTPUT01 DD.

We do this a lot to accomplish the same goal you are trying to achieve.